# C# Form Application Process.Start() Gives Access is denied Error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which gives a cross thread exception when I try to run it with its commands.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// to run the EXE file in the c# code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exeFile">the exe file path and name</param>
    /// <param name="commandLine"></param>
    /// <param name="logArea"></param>
    /// <param name="startButton"></param>
    private void RunExe(string exeFile, string commandLine, RichTextBox logArea, Button startButton)
    {
        process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = exeFile,
                Arguments = commandLine,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            }
        };
        //process instant
        //shell name
        //adding command line as argument to the shell
        //listen to the outputs - non error stream
        //listen to the outputs - error stream
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                logArea.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    AppendLine(e.Data, logArea);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }));
            }
        });

        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            logArea.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                AppendLine(e.Data, logArea);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }));
        });

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        startButton.Invoke(new Action(() => startButton.Enabled = false));

        try
        {
            process.Start(); //start the process instant
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            startButton.Invoke(new Action(() => startButton.Enabled = true));
            GenerateButtonEnable(true);
        }

        process.Close();

        if (startButton == buttonGenerateUT)
        {
            if (UTMatrixStopButton.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UTMatrixStopButton.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    UTMatrixStopButton.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                UTMatrixStopButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {   // invokes required when cross thread tries to reach the ui
            if (IRStopButton.InvokeRequired)
            {
                IRStopButton.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    IRStopButton.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                IRStopButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my function when I start the process Process.Start gives the following error. Funny thing is, everything works fine when I use it as an application. When I try to debug it in the VS, it gives this error.

[image]

Full error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception HResult=0x80004005 Message=Access is denied Source=System StackTrace: at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at SoftwareTestMatrixTool.MainForm.RunExe(String exeFile, String commandLine, RichTextBox logArea, Button startButton) in C:\MYPATH\MainForm.cs:line 669 at SoftwareTestMatrixTool.MainForm.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0() in C:\MYPATH\MainForm.cs:line 613 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

The error shows the caller line of this function.

Comment: Have you tried to run VS as Administrator?

Comment: @SᴇM yes, I am already running it as an Administrator

Comment: Why does that `logArea` watch variable contain a `Cross-thread exception`? Did you try to modify the UI from a background thread? If you get an exception and just ignore it, any exception *after* that could easily be due to the application's state

Comment: In any case you *don't* need all those `Invoke` calls. If you want to update the UI from a background thread use `async/await` or the `IProcess` interface

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` won't help if some other code is blocking the UI thread either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I was modifying the `logarea` with the background process. But this invoking style might be wrong.

Comment: Please, tell us more about this `exeFile` of yours. Is it in your applicaiton's working folder? Was it downloaded/generated by another thread/application? Is it possible that this other thread/app is still blocking it? What happens if you copy `exeFile` into a separate, safe location and then try to run it from there?

Comment: @defaultlocale there is actually a weird behavior here, this is a python exe file and I sent commands to it to run it. I am using c# as a gui to python. It is getting deleted when this exception happen. It is under the same path with all other files just an exe file and its name is just "xxx.exe"

Comment: @Thatshowweroll Deleted? Do you have an antivirus? Have you tried to turn it off?

Comment: I have a company anti-virus and I can not close it unfortunately.

Comment: @defaultlocale it seems that the file is getting deleted so vs seems to have a different issue but this error is related with file's getting deleted so type an answer about it and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Thatshowweroll Can you check the logs of an antivirus? Unfortunately, I don't have enough information to answer your question. You can investigate the issue, validate that the problem is related to antivirus and then post an answer to your own question. This might help future visitors with the same.

Comment: While the documentation for the [Process.SynchronizingObject Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_SynchronizingObject) implies that it only used in the Process.Exited Event, it is also used by the OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived events as well.  Set that property to any control on the UI (including the Form) and the events will be invoked on the UI thread.  That will eliminate the need for your handler code to invoke back to the UI thread when accessing the UI.

Comment: @defaultlocale I am only certain about that I have 2 exe file and one of them getting deleted while in debug mode (but it works fine when I serve the program with a setup). So there are two possibilities; one my using style of UI invoke might be wrong or exe file getting deleted and everything is just fine, the error is just about the exe files deletion process. It is not access error, simple windows can not find the file and vs gives a funky error. Can not test it because I can not reach the domain from home, so I ll give feedback on Monday for this case.

Comment: @defaultlocale I am now sure that this is not a VS error. This is happening because the file is getting deleted by the local defensive program. If you write an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!
Btw I can not find the log of deleting process but I am sure about it.